# counting + sum values in each group to give total for each group

Tags: mysql, database

This is my table for a mysql database. http://the44.simorasic.com/cages.html

I need to show the number of cages for each cage size, along with the total expenditure (cost) in purchasing the cages of that size. Also, to show only the cage size, count of cages and total cost of cages.

What I have so far is this,

```
SELECT cageSize, COUNT(*) as "Number of cages"
from cage
GROUP BY cageSize;
```

So I have managed to count them, but the tricky part is adding the values together for each size, and then giving a total value for each size. Please help as this is part of my assignment, and I am completely stuck. I know I have to create a group for each size, and then sum the values, but can't manage to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for can be found here:

[Group By aggregate functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)

Plus you will need the "WITH ROLLUP" keyword for getting the total.

[Group By modifiers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-modifiers.html)

Comment: this is what i have, 

select cageSize, COUNT(cageSize), SUM(cageCost)
from cage
GROUP BY cageSize WITH ROLLUP;

Results dont look promising, i have null values, and the totals are too big. what am i doing wrong?

Comment: The NULL values are normal, this are the rows that also have the total value. They just don't have a "name".

Comment: When the totals are too big, please check of which datatype cageCost is. You get wrong results when you save it as varchar or anything. Otherwise your query should definitely give you correct results

Comment: tombom, i dont know what you are talking about. ive been doing sql for 3 weeks, and i only know basics. If i just do a basic count for each cageSize, such as this, 

SELECT cageCost, cageSize, COUNT(*) as "Number of cages"
from cage
GROUP BY cageSize;

I get 25 for B, 29 for E etc... this is way too much, there are only 6 B values in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [`SUM`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) function in MySql to sum up your `cageCost` values.

`SUM` is an aggregate function like `COUNT` is so will work in the same fashion across a `GROUP BY`.