# MySQL group records that are similar, and then give the group total

Tags: mysql

I have a set of data that I'm trying to manipulate in order to achieve some results. In the one table, I have different waste types stored like this:

```
-----------------------------
| id  | wastetype | percent |
|-----|-----------|---------|
|  1  |    12     |   30    |
|  2  |    12     |   20    |
|  3  |    12     |   10    |
-----------------------------
```

Basically, what I want to do is display an accumulation of all the waste types in the table, given a specific wastetype ID. I would like to accomplish this using the database, so that the PHP code I have can then use the result from the query in any further calculations or print the result. I know if I use `COUNT` it won't count the values contained in the fields but it would count the number of times they appeared in the table.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9821649/counting-sum-values-in-each-group-to-give-total-for-each-group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SUM` instead of `COUNT`. Try,

```
SELECT SUM(percent) totalPercentage
FROM tableName
WHERE wasteType = 1
```

OR

```
SELECT wastetype, SUM(percent) totalPercentage
FROM tableName
GROUP BY wasteType
WHERE wasteType = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT COUNT(*) AS num, SUM(percent) AS sum_percent FROM table GROUP BY wastetype;`

`GROUP BY` groups records with same values for the given field(s) together. Using [grouping functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) allows you to collect information on grouped data.